# Possible endogeneity issue with FE regression

Tags: least-squares, assumptions, endogeneity, simultaneity

I am doing a regression of the effects of sanctions on gdp:

```
Baseline <- lm(log(GDP) ~ EU + UN + Resources + PTS + PolityV + Schooling + Trade + Mortality + factor(Country) + factor(Year), data = RegressionData)
```

When writing about the OLS assumptions i realized that, as far as I understand it, in Introductory economics by Wooldridge, it says that there must not be a lagged effect of any X to Y and no feedback effects from Y to Z for the assumption of the mean of the error term being 0 not to be violated. Resources and Trade are both in % of GDP of the same year, because the world bank data didnt have them as absolute datasets. My question here is, do i have a problem of endogeneity because there is a connection between those two independent variables and the GDP?

For example, if the absolute trade volume stays the same, but the GDP increases in that year, "Trade" would decrease.